# Find two different pattern and match count

Tags: perl

I need to find how many 10 and 01 s are there in the sting. for ex: 10101 in this, two 10 are there and two 01 are there like that use reg ex and find it ? and print the 10 is match 2 times and 01 match the 2 times

Comment: [And what have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) Remember, your question should show some research effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [goatse operator](http://search.cpan.org/dist/perlsecret/lib/perlsecret.pod#Goatse__=%28_%29=) `=()=`:

```
$string = '10101';

$a =()= $string =~ m/10/g;
$b =()= $string =~ m/01/g;

print "a: $a\nb: $b\n";
```

The output is:

```
a: 2
b: 2
```

Comment: Thanks.... but how to use regular expression using...this question?

Comment: @reegana Sorry, I don't get what you mean. Here the regexps are given by `/10/g` and `/01/g`.

Comment: Bad choice of var names.

Comment: god help me to unsee what goatse means. never google it. sorry for offtopic

Comment: @Zaid You are right but I think it is not that difficult here to understand what `$a` and `$b` are for.

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $test = "101010";

my @matches_10 = $test =~ m!10!g;
my @matches_01 = $test =~ m!01!g;
print "matches 10: ", scalar(@matches_10), "\n"; #<-- prints: 3
print "matches 01: ", scalar(@matches_01), "\n"; #<-- prints: 2
```